# Transmission line simulation in LTspice: How to model a CMOS input?

Tags: pcb, mosfet, simulation, cmos, ltspice

I am trying to simulate the effect of a PCB trace on a clock signal with LTspice, see the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

In my quick and dirty setup, the clock receiver is the resistor Rin. In the real world, it is a DAC with a CMOS input. Is there an easy way to model such an input in LTspice? Is the resistor accurate enough?

Comment: a sniff of capacitance would be better, 5pF give or take.

Comment: R only? NO  Cin depends on family of CMOS and Vdd,  of which there are dozens.   All CMOS is rated at a fixed load pF which, due to RdsON of output driver limits the slew rate. So which family? More important is to  simulate a track w/g dimension ratio to ground with related Zo and length? This gives the 2nd order response to ringing, Not RdsOn*Ciss which is 1st order . ok?

Comment: (also in real scopes, the length of probe ground and L value.

Comment: What's wrong with a plain `NMOS`/`PMOS`?

Answer (score -4):

\$Z_0 = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} = \sqrt{\frac{1874,79 \text{nH}}{56,98 \text{pF}}} = 181,3907313029 \Omega\$

add resistor  180Ω  (Rin || 180Ω).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: You are calculating the trace impedance, how does it answer the question?